# What is the Use of Heartbeat.aspx in Sitecore

Tags: content-editor

I have been noticing this heartbeat.aspx in few blogs.But nothing explains the use of heartbeat.aspx,What exatcly is hearbeat.aspx and how/when can i use it ?

Comment: This can likely shed some light on heartbeat: https://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2018/02/sitecore-event-queue-visual-diagram/ (search page for "heartbeat") I don't recall seeing heartbeat.aspx in my discovery though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can access `Heartbeat.aspx` via `/sitecore/service/heartbeat.aspx` url.

`Heartbeat.aspx` checks if all your SQL databases configured in your `connectionStrings` config are accessible.

I they are accessible, it just render empty response.

If at least one of the databases is not accessible, it returns `500 Internal Error` page and writes to the log file lines like:

> 5112 16:42:04 FATAL SINGLE MSG: Sitecore heartbeat:
>
> Exception: System.Exception
>
> Message: Database ........................ is not available

You can exclude some of the connection strings from being checked by Hearbeat using `"Sitecore.Services.Heartbeat.ExcludeConnection"` setting:

```
<setting 
  name="Sitecore.Services.Heartbeat.ExcludeConnection"
  value="some-connection-string-name-1|another-connection-string-name-2"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

We have faced a similar fatal issue when using Redis Cache to store user sessions:

> FATAL SINGLE MSG: Sitecore heartbeat:
>   Exception: System.Exception
>   Message: Database redis.cache is not available

So I would recommend to exclude your "sessions" connection string from checks too.